# Video Editing Software that Allows Me To Edit Multiple Audio Tracks Seperately from 1 Video File?

Tags: sound, video, video-editor, editing

So OBS (my recording software) has a feature that allows me to record multiple audio tracks into one video. For example, I can have my microphone and desktop audio recorded in separate audio tracks that both get recorded onto one single video file, and then when using an editing software that supports it, I can edit my microphone's audio separate from my desktop audio. However, I have yet to find a program that can do this that's compatible with Linux. I prefer said program be free.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you don't mention which you have tested but some applications worth trying are

- shotcut
- blender [there is a very nice tutorial series on youtube on how to use it as a video editor]
- kdenlive
- lwks

[don't know it they support what you want]